# Javascript in Squarespace isn't working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, code-injection, squarespace

I have a custom form that uses javascript that I'd like to add to my site. What the form does, is in stead of having a text label it has an image label which will change when a user hovers over the image or selects the image. I have tested it outside of Squarespace and it seems to be working fine. It isn't working on Squarespace. I have tried putting the HTML/CSS/javascript together in a code block, I have tried putting the CSS in the custom CSS area, and I have tried using code injector to put the javascript in. Nothing seems to be working. The HTML/CSS show up perfectly, it's just that nothing happens when you hover or click on the image. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$('#spiritWhiskeyCandle img').hover(
     function () {
         if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
             $(this).attr('src', 'http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/thedetroitbox/SpiritWhiskeyh_zpsf291cbeb.png');
         }
      },
     function () {
         if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
             $(this).attr('src', 'http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/thedetroitbox/SpiritWhiskey_zps968a5a84.png');
         }
     }
  );


$("#spiritWhiskeyCandle img").click(function() {
    if($(this).next().val() !== "1") {
         $(this).attr("src", "http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/thedetroitbox/SpiritWhiskeyc_zps62af06c4.png");
         $(this).next().val("1");
    } else {
         $(this).attr("src", "http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/thedetroitbox/SpiritWhiskey_zps968a5a84.png");
         $(this).next().val("0");
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#spiritWhiskeyCandle {
width:24%;
height:0;
padding-bottom:24%;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin-right:1%;
margin-bottom:1%;
}

#spiritWhiskeyCandle img {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <label for="T3I1" id="spiritWhiskeyCandle">
        <img src="http://i1380.photobucket.com/albums/ah191/thedetroitbox/SpiritWhiskey_zps968a5a84.png">
        <input name="T3I1" type="radio" id="T3I1" style="display:none">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have jquery included on your squarespace site? Do you have your javascript code inside a `$(document).ready` function? do you get any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: I do not have jquery included on my site. I did not have a $(document).ready function, though I just added it and am still not seeing anything happen. I am not getting any errors.

Comment: you do not have jquery included on your site or was that a typo? Also, is this live somewhere? It would help solve the problem if we could see it reproduced. Also - are the images added dynamically?

Comment: Nope, not a typo I don't have jquery - I'm not really sure that I need it? You can view the page here: www.thedetroitbox.com/test-page

Comment: Can you update the site to not use the answer provided below? That won't work and breaks the rest of the javascript on your page

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just switched it back to what I had before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery since you are using jquery functions. Add this snippet before the rest of your javascript. Preferably in the `head` section

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This along with the $(document).ready function fixed it.