# JavaScript imagemappro.js editor integration in Squarespace

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I am attempting to add a JavaScript element to a Squarespace page. I am not a Squarespace dev so I'm pulling my hair out with all their menus and work arounds.

I have a page that I want to add a script to:

https://red-trout-aldy.squarespace.com/map/

The password to view the site is: CheckMeOut

The script isn't showing on the page and is giving me a 404 status when I view it the Inspector and the CSS I added to the Squarespace "CSS" page is showing as "canceled." I added the javascript as a Code Block and used the "HTML" option in the Code Block. I think that the problem lies somewhere in the "Script SRC" tag, but I'm not sure.

I have followed the instructions on this post:
[Javascript in Squarespace isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095317/javascript-in-squarespace-isnt-working)

But adding the snippet to my Header didn't help

Here is a copy of the code that I was given to add to the page:

```
 <div id="image-map-pro-container"></div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    ;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#image-map-pro-container').imageMapPro({"id":1596,"editor":{"selected_shape":"rect-2290","tool":"rect","shapeCounter":{"rects":5}},"general":{"name":"Untitled"},"spots":[{"id":"rect-1110","title":"Area 1","type":"rect","x":12.125,"y":21.333,"width":25.5,"height":25.111,"x_image_background":12.125,"y_image_background":21.333,"width_image_background":25.5,"height_image_background":25.111,"actions":{"click":"follow-link","link":"Google.com"},"default_style":{"opacity":0.5299145299145299,"border_radius":10,"background_color":"Black","background_opacity":0.3999732905982906,"border_width":7},"mouseover_style":{"border_radius":10},"tooltip_content":{"squares_settings":{"containers":[{"id":"sq-container-403761","settings":{"elements":[{"settings":{"name":"Heading","iconClass":"fa fa-header"},"options":{"heading":{"text":"Rect 0"}}}]}}]}}},{"id":"rect-1185","title":"Area 2","type":"rect","x":51,"y":29.333,"width":36,"height":48.444,"x_image_background":51,"y_image_background":29.333,"width_image_background":36,"height_image_background":48.444,"actions":{"click":"follow-link","link":"yahoo.com"},"default_style":{"border_radius":10,"background_color":"Green","background_opacity":0.7504006410256411},"mouseover_style":{"border_radius":10},"tooltip_content":{"squares_settings":{"containers":[{"id":"sq-container-403761","settings":{"elements":[{"settings":{"name":"Heading","iconClass":"fa fa-header"},"options":{"heading":{"text":"Rect 3"}}}]}}]}}},{"id":"rect-2290","title":"Area 3","type":"rect","x":4.375,"y":48.889,"width":40.625,"height":42.667,"x_image_background":4.375,"y_image_background":48.889,"width_image_background":40.625,"height_image_background":42.667,"static":1,"actions":{"click":"follow-link","link":"msn.com"},"default_style":{"border_radius":2,"background_color":"#123456","background_opacity":0.9726228632478633,"border_width":13,"border_color":"#aaaa5f"},"mouseover_style":{"border_radius":10},"tooltip_content":{"squares_settings":{"containers":[{"id":"sq-container-60621","settings":{"elements":[{"settings":{"name":"Heading","iconClass":"fa fa-header"},"options":{"heading":{"text":"THIS IS A TOOL TIP"}}}]}}]}}}]});
             });
    })(jQuery, window, document);
</script>
```

Comment: I have checked your link but didn't get a 404 status after I entered the password

Comment: I inspected and I found the js script is injected but there is no div with an id of "image-map-pro-container"?

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine - Sorry for the confusion...the PAGE doesn't give a 404, the .JS was showing as 404 under the "Status" column in the Inspector.

Comment: I have solved part of the problem by changing some of the code and uploading a file:

I changed the line 3 in the code to:
`<script src="scripts/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>`

and uploaded the .js file into a "scripts" folder on the server. Now I am seeing the DIV on the page, but the CSS is still showing as "canceled" in the inspector and the CSS isn't working.

Comment: I think I found your problem the image-map-pro.min.js is not loading are you sure it's under scripts folder or try using a CDN for the library imagemap pro

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine 

I just figured that out too. Now the DIV is showing, but the CSS still isn't working.

Comment: for me, the website is still not loading the scripts/image-map-pro.min.js file when you inspect go to the console check this line, "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imageMapPro is not a function" it means the script is not loaded yet

Comment: @ChamsddineBouzaine - It seems to be fully working now. By adding the script to the correct location on the server and... I had to inject the full CSS manually, not using a link to the stylesheet. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

As @ChamsddineBouzaine noted, the code that I was given by the application I am using was incorrect. I changed the line that said

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/image-map-pro.min.js"></script>
```

I uploaded the "image-map-pro.min.js" file to a folder on the server called, "scripts"

I was also told by the app developers to add a line into the header of the site:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-map-pro.min.css">
```

Even after adding this file to the server, it wouldn't work. I kept getting an error saying:

> Refused to apply style from
> 'https://red-trout-aldy.squarespace.com/css/image-map-pro.min.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
> type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

So I had to open the CSS file in Dreamweaver and manually paste it into the "INSERT CSS" page on Squarespace and point the CSS to the Collection Number for the body of the /map page. I found the technique on this youtube video:

[Page Specific CSS for Squarespace](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0AR09lDi8M)

Comment: Yes. It is working correctly now. The way that Squarespace works still kinda confuses me. Thanks for your help.